# ORM for GSQL, LINQ 2 GSQL?

Tags: .net, linq, google-app-engine, orm

is there LINQ 2 GSQL implementation ?

**Note :** GSQL is the query language (SQL subset) used in Google AppEngine datastore

Comment: Please specify what you mean with GSQL. From a quick googling i found http://gsql.org/news/ and references to a groovy library.

If it is one of those, then no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language is called 'GQL', not 'GSQL', and such an ORM isn't really possible - .net applications do not run on App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you obviously can't use Microsoft's LINQ on App Engine, but there are of course other systems for object-relational mapping.

In fact, App Engine's `db.Model` has a lot of the features of an ORM (although internally the database isn't relational, so the 'R' in ORM doesn't quite work): data is retrieved from the datastore as objects of a particular class, and you can access the "columns" just like properties. As in Linq-to-SQL, you define the data model by creating a language-native class with members, not by writing datastore queries.

So I would say you can have an "ORM" of sorts on App Engine: in fact, it's the default way to use the datastore.